# С# WindowsForms WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser

Здравствуйте! Я хочу создать приложение для ПК на C# я сам пока новичок.
Для графического интерфейса я выбрал windows forms
Приложение основывается на компонент WebBrowser
В окне будет только два компонента адресная строка и сам браузер
Если в адресную строку написать какое-то адрес и нажать на интер на браузере будет отображаться контент.

А теперь внимание

Надо на одну текстовой документ вылить список адресов куда обращается браузер.

Comment: судя по ошибкам русский язык у вас не родной... но все же, большую часть текста я понял, вроде даже правильно, но постарайтесь чуть подробнее описать сам вопрос, лучше простыми предложениями, пока сам вопрос не очень понятен.

Comment: забудьте все что я написал. Чтобы лучше объяснить именно какой метод я ищу приведу пример от андроида, в андроиде есть метод shouldOverrideUrlLoading если вы не знаете эту метод посмотрите в интернете её структуру я ищу метод типа такого.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно событие WebBrowser.Navigated
Это событие происходит, когда WebBrowser переходит в новый документ и начинает его загрузку.

```
// Updates the URL in TextBoxAddress upon navigation.
private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    toolStripTextBox1.Text = e.Url.ToString();
    // or
    toolStripTextBox1.Text = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
}
```

Вот тут больше:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowsernavigatedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx